# Is it possible to check if a non-blocking socket has been shutdown?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I want to check if a socket is still alive before I try to read from it, but it seems like recv() and read() will return 0 regardless. According to the man page:

> When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).

But also:

> The value 0 may also be returned if the requested number of bytes to receive from a stream socket was 0.

How do I distinguish between these two cases? And if that's not possible, is there some other method to tell is the socket has been shutdown/closed?

Comment: In real world scenarios, you will rarely, if ever, request a read operation of 0 bytes. I've been coding sockets for almost 20 years and have never needed to do it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm just trying to fix a bug in a code written long time ago, while making hopefully small changes, but it looks like that MSG_PEEK flag is a good approach, if it allows to check the socket while leaving the stream unchanged.

Comment: This won't fix anything. This kind of thing is doomed to failure. You are essentially trying to predict the future. The connection can be closed between the test and the actual read. What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `recv()` with a non-zero `length` and the `MSG_PEEK` flag. Then check whether the return value is `0`. Using `MSG_PEEK` will prevent this from consuming any of the data -- the next `recv()` will read it again.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above is correct answer.

Non-blocking socket will return -1 and set errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK if there is simply no new data.
In case of graceful connection shutdown by the remote peer recv will return 0.